# Installing Node.js - No such file or direktory

Tags: node.js, linux, centos

I have removed node.js on my CentOS. After that I was installing a new version node.js. Now I can't run the node.js:

> -bash: /usr/local/bin/node: No such file or direktory

The only solution is to create a link

> ln -s /usr/bin/node /usr/local/bin/node

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

Recommend you to use [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm), very simple and can avoid many problems.

step one:
`curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.8/install.sh | bash`

step two:
`nvm install stable`

Check if successful:
`node -v`

Answer (score 0):

I have solution for my problem. After **re-login**, everything is fine. I think the problem was somewhere in the **ENV** setup and reloaded after new login.